# Designing an ASP.NET MVC 3 site to support customer-specific view customization without forking

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, multi-tenant

I'm working on a big ASP.NET MVC site, a commerce service sold to customers. We sell mostly to small and large institutions so it's not shrinkwrap-scale. These large customers will ask us to make customizations, mostly wider than but including customizing the layout to fit with their site.

Our current thinking is that even with MVC followed through to its natural conclusion with very simple controllers that only call other code (as recommended), the views will be a hard problem because they don't lend themselves well to this kind of composability, in any case not with Razor as we've been using. It's hard to subclass them and say "for this customer, do something a bit extra"; particularly, it's hard to serve up slightly different HTML for the same construct.

We can't figure out making either of multi-tenancy and single-tenancy work cleanly, and we don't wish to fork the codebase, even if the customizations for one or more customers are thorough. (To the extent possible, we want to keep the database structure isomorphic across all our customers, which I guess is the way we would do it for multi-tenancy, but every tenant will have to be their own IIS web site because of scale and isolation.) Even if we came up with a way of overlaying a layer of custom views, that would allow for the opportunity of slight logic mismatches within the views.

What's the current state of the art of doing this? What are the war stories? (This could be subjective, but it's mostly objective in that if there's a pattern or an approach that completely cuts this down to its essence, of course that's the right answer. And I think it's an interesting question.)

I am happy to provide more detail.

Comment: An update: We're still reviewing this and are fixing other architectural issues in the meantime. I still intend to accept an answer by the time we figure out what to do.

Comment: Yet another update: We still haven't gotten to this stage. I'm thinking of asking Stack Exchange how they do it, since it strikes me that they have exactly our problem except for synchronized feature sets. I don't mean to hold out on selecting an answer, so I have accepted @tvanfosson's answer on the merits of being the one grounded in personal experience and having very specific advice from that, but I will probably need to reevaluate this in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've recently developed a site to support our 5 Regents institutions.  Since we have a fixed set of customers, which is very unlikely to grow, we've made some choices that you might not make.  For example, we have a separate database instance per customer. Clearly that doesn't scale very well, but it does simplify the model significantly so for us it works.

The strategies that I've used are:

1. Focus on features and configurations, not customers.  We have a set of core features for every institution.  Only a few of those features are customizable.  For each institution, we maintain a Web.Config transform that contains their choices for the customizable features.  A publishing setting is used to control which transform is used when publishing that institution's app.  The view/controller uses the configuration data to implement the variant of the feature specified for that institution.  It doesn't know which institution it is, just that the configuration says "do A, instead of B, when rendering widget C."
2. Separate themes into common and site-specific components.  Most of the CSS/images are common to all institutions, however, we load site-specific CSS last allowing overrides for a particular site.  This is mainly colors, backgrounds, and institution-specific images (banners and such).  We put site-specific themes in separate folders within `content/themes`.  A configuration item is used to set the theme folder and the master views pull this configuration item when constructing the url for the CSS and any site-specific images (most, if not all, of it is handled in the site CSS file itself).
3. Maintain a strongly-typed configuration class that wraps the standard configuration.  Inject this class into controllers, mailers, etc. wherever the configuration is needed.  Because we rely on configuration through-out the application we felt that promoting this to a first-class entity within our model was important for readability and maintainability. For non-binary options we typically create `enums` that map to the setting to avoid string comparisons. For a more complex application or more institutions I would probably even develop a separate configuration section handler and separate the configuration into it's own section or config file.  For now, ours uses `appsettings` as the number of settings is small and they are relatively simple.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, it's very helpful. It's not 100% applicable since we can get entire "chains" of institutions as separate customers so we don't have the luxury of staticity in that aspect, but most of the advice still applies. Particularly the bit about separating the features (which customers may adopt and drop from time to time) from the identity customization. Even if no code or layout customization is ever requested, we will definitely need different payment processing identities and certainly basic things like the name and address of the institution; we'll look at unifying all of these things.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to look at multi-tenancy views, there was [a good article on the subject by Rob Ashton a while ago](http://codeofrob.com/entries/multi-tenancy-in-asp.net-mvc---controller-actions-part-ii.html).

Comment: +1. This looks nice and matches the conclusions we've drawn already of minimizing the support burden. If Rob provides more tips in the category (which I'm now looking into), this could be what we want.

Comment: IIRC he did do a mini series on the topic, but that's a bit hard to find with his site down. Perhaps ask him on twitter.

Comment: Oh, Internet Archive, let me count the ways I love you: http://web.archive.org/web/20100909182628/http://www.codeofrob.com/category/10.aspx

Comment: I'm reviewing this right now. If no one has anything else to add by the time I'm finished, I think I've got my answer.

Comment: Edited the answer to point to the live article since it's back up [(the last one, since it has links to the previous ones)](http://codeofrob.com/entries/multi-tenancy-in-asp.net-mvc---controller-actions-part-ii.html).